# Laravel 5.6 CSRF Token fails when POST made via Ajax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using a WYSIWYG editor and wish to post media to a controller, this operation is done via ajax.

In the header I have:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I've added an additional request header;

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

$('textarea.default').froalaEditor({
  requestHeaders: {
    _token: token,
  },
  charCounterCount: false,
})
```

However, when the ajax fires I get a `419 unknown status error` but I'm posting my CSRF token along with request so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Can you confirm the csrf-token `meta` tag is within the `<head>` of your html?

Comment: Yes I can console.log() the token variable and it displays the token

Answer (score 0):

Make sure meta tag with name 'csrf-token' exists

OR

**Use this in your ajax:**

```
_token: {{csrf_token()}},
```

If it does not work then send csrf token in data object of ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: '////',
        data: {_token: {{csrf_token()}}},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear, I'm not making the AJAX call additional headers is just a parameter I can use with my WYSIWYG editor